# Is it possible to create an Area within an Area?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-areas

Assuming I have to insert another MVC Project A with Area(s) into another MVC Project B. Which means I have to create an Area in MVC project B  and insert the files with Area from MVC Project A

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK nested areas are not supported. If you need that you might consider splitting your application into 2 separate applications. And inside the Admin application use areas.